# Jquery ajax request failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a web application and I have a little problem to send data to the server with Ajax
my goal is to do a double with ajax request

Except that the varible $ _GET['lang'] does not exist on the server side! (PHP)

[here my code.js](http://fouka.alwaysdata.net/code.js)

Code:

```
jQuery.ajax ({ 
    type: "GET" 
    url: URL, 
    like: "json" 
    success: function (response) { 
        var jsonp = response; 
        var obj =jQuery.parseJSON (jsonp).; 
        jQuery.each (obj, function () { 
            lang + = this ['value'] + ":" + this ['qualify'] split ('@') [4] split ('s') [1] + "\ n".. }); 
            alert (lang);
            jQuery.ajax({ 
                type:"GET" 
                url:"SaveFileFromClient.php" 
                data: "lang =" + lang, 
                success: function (response) { } 
            }); 
        } 
});
```

Comment: Can you post the AJAX request code and PHP code here?

Comment: jQuery.ajax ({
type: "GET"
url: URL,
like: "json"
success: function (response) {
var jsonp = response;
var obj =jQuery.parseJSON (jsonp).;
jQuery.each (obj, function () {
lang + = this ['value'] + ":" + this ['qualify'] split ('@') [4] split ('s') [1] + "\ n"..
});
alert (lang);
/ / I send the lang variable to the server with Ajax
jQuery.ajax({
type:"GET"
url:"SaveFileFromClient.php"
data: "lang =" + lang,
success: function (response) {
}
});
}
});

Comment: Formatted the best I could..this is just riddled with syntax errors...what's your console say?

Comment: what is the `like` ajax option supposed to do? is the first request completing? where is `lang` defined?

Comment: the option like this is to show that the output format is json file types;
this is why I must make two ajax queries;
the second to write my json file in csv parser and write on the server and deal with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure:

```
jQuery.ajax ({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: URL, 
    dataType : "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var l=data.length;
        for(i=0;i<l;i++){
            lang+=data[i]['value']+ ": "+ data[i]['qualify'].split('@')[4].split('s')[1]+"\n"; 
            alert (lang);
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"SaveFileFromClient.php",
                data: {lang:lang},
                async : false,
                success: function (response) { } 
            }
        } 
});
```

Also pay attention to the max size of the string passed through GET